# pyodbc insert query with where clause with variable values

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I want to insert different variable values in SQl where the values must not be present in the table  using pyodbc but gets error.

### variables

```
for data in datafield:
  id = data.Id
  iname = data.name
  ivalue = data.value
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Description (SrId, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (?, ?, ?) WHERE IN (SELECT * from Description WHERE SrId <>id AND FieldName<>iname AND FieldValue<>ivalue)", (id, iname, ivalue))
  connection.commit()
```

Using Pyodbc to connect the Sql server with python

**Error : Syntax error**

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, there is no `VALUES...WHERE` syntax. Consider an insert-select with a [`LEFT JOIN...NULL`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) on [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to avoid duplicates:

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT WITH QMARK PLACEHOLDERS
sql = """INSERT INTO Description (SrId, FieldName, FieldValue) 
         SELECT vals.SrId, vals.FieldName, vals.FieldValue
         FROM Description d
         LEFT JOIN (VALUES (?, ?, ?)) AS vals(SrId, FieldName, FieldValue)   
           ON d.SrId  = vals.SrId 
           AND d.FieldName = vals.FieldName
           AND d.FieldValue = vals.FieldValue
         WHERE d.SrId IS NULL 
            OR d.FieldName IS NULL
            OR d.FielValue IS NULL
      """

# BIND PARAMS
cur.execute(sql, (id, iname, ivalue))
connection.commit()
```

Comment: Hi Parfait - Thanks for the answer, But while running the above script the data keeps on repeating in the Table everytime when run the script. What i require is once the data with particular [ ID, iname, ivalue] has been inserted must not be while running the script for the second time .

Comment: See update using a table value constructor. In hindsight, previous query would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `"` at the end of the line.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Description (SrId, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (?, ?, ?) WHERE IN (SELECT * from Description WHERE SrId <>id AND FieldName<>iname AND FieldValue<>ivalue)", (id, iname, ivalue)")
```

Should be

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Description (SrId, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (?, ?, ?) WHERE IN (SELECT * from Description WHERE SrId <>id AND FieldName<>iname AND FieldValue<>ivalue)", (id, iname, ivalue))
```

Comment: Checked with the suggested code as well but still the same error